# Volttron on MacOS issue with vcfg

Tags: macos, volttron

Running into the issue below while trying to run vcfg command in Volttron on my Mac use iTerm. Any help would be much appreciated.

'''

```
(volttron)cg@Carolyns-MacBook-Pro volttron % vcfg

Your VOLTTRON_HOME currently set to: /Users/cg/.volttron

Is this the volttron you are attempting to setup? [Y]:
Message bus set to zmq
What is the vip address? [tcp://127.0.0.1]:
What is the port for the vip address? [22916]:
Is this instance web enabled? [N]: Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cg/volttron/env/bin/vcfg", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('volttron', 'console_scripts', 'vcfg')()
  File "/Users/cg/volttron/volttron/platform/config.py", line 593, in _main
    main()
  File "/Users/cg/volttron/volttron/platform/instance_setup.py", line 862, in main
    wizard()
  File "/Users/cg/volttron/volttron/platform/instance_setup.py", line 748, in wizard
    do_web_enabled_zmq(volttron_home)
  File "/Users/cg/volttron/volttron/platform/instance_setup.py", line 433, in do_web_enabled_zmq
    'https://' + get_hostname())
  File "/Users/cg/volttron/volttron/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in get_hostname
    with open('/etc/hostname') as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/hostname'
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/hostname` does not exist on Mac. The documentation for Volttron indicates that it [only supports Linux operating systems.](https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron#background). It seems like you'll have to use a Linux host (or use virtualization).